# Using Select and GroupBy in a Dataset using LINQ and returning multiple DataRows

Tags: linq, datatable

I have a `DataTable` as below:

```
Term|ChildTerm|ID|PID
---------------------
BOTH|         |1 |5
    |A        |1 |5
    |B        |1 |5
   F|         |2 |5
    |f        |2 |5
    |F        |2 |5
   M|         |3 |5
    |m        |3 |5
    |M        |3 |5
   E|         |4 |6
    |e        |4 |6
    |E        |4 |6
    |Em       |4 |6
```

I would like to have a select where PID =5 and Group by ID 
therefore i need to get three dataRows "Both","F","M" how can i achieve this

I have written the following code

```
var NCIIDS = PCGTDS.Tables[strTableName]
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .GroupBy(Row => Row.Field<string>("PID") == "5")
                   .Select(Value => Value.First());

foreach (DataRow PCNCIIDS in NCIIDS)
{
    //some operation on the data row
}
```

But this only returns the First Value as the `Select` statement returns only one in the Linq `Select`. How do i get all the three records?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to Solve this by the following code

```
 var ncid = from NCI in PCGTDS.Tables[strTableName].AsEnumerable()
                                   group NCI by NCI.Field<string>("PID") == "5";

                        foreach (var n in ncid)
                        {
                            if (n.Key)
                            {
                                foreach (var value in n)
                                {

                                }
                            }

                        }
```